# Import activity from GitHub

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I would like to integrate my GitHub account with StackOverflow (SO) so that I can share my open source contributions in my developer CV. Since I don't have office experience, my developer CV looks almost empty.

How can I add my GitHub projects and other open-source contributions to my StackOverflow developer CV?

Comment: Doesn't the "add or update: [GitHub] [..]" button work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 'Open Source' section of your CV there is a section that allows you to import projects from various providers:

[image: add or update]

You can click one of these, follow the auth prompts and you'll be able to select projects that you want shown on your CV.

Comment: I don't see a OpenSource section in my CV. But I have seen that in a couple of others' CV. Why is it unavailable on mine?

Comment: Now, I am able to import projects from providers. It looks like a user needs to have more than 1.5K reputation to unlock the open source section in CV. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ArunKumar it's not rep related, but it looks like we hide certain fields in some circumstances. I'll investigate tomorrow once I'm back at a laptop

Comment: I was motivated to update my Story today thanks to an email from SO and I have no options to import at all, on any of the edit views I can find. Manually adding projects from GitHub is so tedious…

Comment: This method does not work with the new, updated Developer Story pages. ([See answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354415/3357935))

Answer (score 1):

The process for importing projects from GitHub has changed with the introduction of Developer Stories.

- Open your [Developer Story page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current)
- Scroll down to **Add a new item** and select **Open source**

  [image: Open source button]
- Click **Import from GitHub**

  [image: Import from GitHub button]
- Select a project by clicking **Add**

  [image: Selecting a project to add]